# Characters in TextView not displayed properly while typing

Tags: android, layout, textview

I made a TextView and a button. Clicking on the button will save the value entered by the user in a variable. The problem is, when the keyboard pops up after touching the textview, only the first character will be visible properly. The rest of the characters aren't displayed. An _ appears instead of the other characters. After i'm done typing and press the back button and when the keyboard disappears, I can see the characters properly. What is the problem?

```
    Button okbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
    okbutton.setClickable(true);
    final TextView radius = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radius);

    okbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    i=radius.getText().toString();
    }
    });
```

Here is the complete layout

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:src="@drawable/settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"></ImageView>

   <TextView android:textSize="20px" android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/alarmset"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/alarmset"
    android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"
    android:drawablePadding="10px" android:paddingTop="10px"></TextView>

<TextView android:text="@string/distance" android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/alarmset"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/kmvalue" android:layout_below="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<TextView android:text="@string/km" android:id="@+id/km"
    android:layout_below="@+id/distance" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kmvalue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"></TextView>

<TextView android:text="@string/musichooser" android:id="@+id/musictext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/km" android:paddingTop="10px"></TextView>

<Button android:id="@+id/chooser" android:layout_below="@+id/musictext"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/lov_ena"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30px" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/musicfile">
</Button>

<EditText android:id="@+id/musicfile" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/musictext" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/chooser"
    android:layout_height="40px">
</EditText>

<TextView android:text="@string/imgchooser" android:id="@+id/imgText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chooser" android:paddingTop="20px"></TextView>

<Button android:id="@+id/imgPicker" android:layout_below="@+id/imgText"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/lov_ena"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30px" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imgfile">
</Button>

<EditText android:id="@+id/imgfile" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgText" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/chooser"
    android:layout_height="40px">
</EditText>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true">


    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50px" android:id="@+id/setalarm"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:text="@string/setalarm" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgfile"
    android:text="Enter Distance" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/okbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="OK" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/radius"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgfile"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/okbutton" />

      </RelativeLayout>
```

This image should make the problem easy to understand 
http://i39.tinypic.com/r8t64l.jpg

Comment: XML layout seems ok. Better post the whole xml layout code.

Comment: strange issue paste your complete layout and code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `TextView` in your Code to `EditText`.

Comment: I tried changing TextView to EditText. But that didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Button okbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

```
okbutton.setClickable(true);

EditText radius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.radius);

okbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
i=radius.getText().toString();
}
});
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

by mistake you have puted any other view over your edit-text; jus go to your xml file and open Graphical layout, then find that view using mouse-pointer by clicking on that part in which your can not see the text in your shown picture, by double-clicking on that part you can goto xml, and jus remove that view from your xml

Comment: Nope. Its actually funny. I run the same code in a different emulator and it worked fine. On a physical device(Samsung galaxy fit) the box didn't show. But on a Samsung galaxy ace it was working normal. Couldn't figure out why.

Comment: ya.In emulator, the box is displayed. But on phone the box is not displayed.